# Postgres lightweight database for testing purpose

Tags: java, postgresql, testing

What is the easiest way to initialize some **lightweight PostgreSQL instance** (probably in some temp directory) from java code. I need some temporary database for running the test; so best way will be to create/drop that cluster (database) before/after running the tests.

Is there some java library for that? Is it possible with pure java code, without external scripts?

My stack is Java, Maven, jetty, TestNG, PostgreSQL.

Comment: https://github.com/yandex-qatools/postgresql-embedded

Comment: Maybe you just need DBUnit

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque: DBUnit still needs a database to connect to.

Comment: Fairly common question. Nobody I know of has written a Java library for it. (Everyone who asks for one seems unwilling to write one). You'll need to invoke `initdb` and `postgres` commands via `ProcessBuilder` etc. Pretty easy really.

Comment: Hm, I take it back. There's https://github.com/adrianboimvaser/postgresql-maven-plugin .

Answer (score 2):

Use [the PostgreSQL maven plugin](https://github.com/adrianboimvaser/postgresql-maven-plugin), which is designed for the purpose.

You'll need to tell it where PostgreSQL's binaries are if it can't find them on the `PATH`.

---

If you want to roll your own you'll need to:

- Invoke `initdb` via `ProcessBuilder` to create a temp data directory.
- Make any necessary changes to `pg_hba.conf` or generate a new one
- Invoke `postgres` via `ProcessBuilder` to start PostgreSQL

Your `ProcessBuilder` must set up the `PATH` environment variable so PostgreSQL can find its other binaries.

You don't have to generate a custom `postgresql.conf`, as you can just pass parameters on the command line, e.g.

```
postgres -D some-datadir -c port=5599 -c listen_addresses='127.0.0.1'
```

etc. But if you want, you can just append a single line to the default `postgresql.conf` like

```
include 'myapp-test.conf'
```

then generate/copy a `myapp-test.conf` file containing all the PostgreSQL config settings you want. This can be easier if you have lots of settings and/or complex ones due to command line length limits, and it can be more readable/debuggable.

Do not use the default port when starting PostgreSQL for testing. Always override the port.

Answer (score 0):

depends on what exactly do you need. only the database to be up and running? or also manage data between tests?

1. [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) will help you start and stop db.
2. [dbunit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) will help you prepare data for your test.

   cons:

   - a lot of work is required to create and maintain schema and data. especially when your project is in a intensive development stage.
   - it's another abstraction layer so if suddenly you want to use some db feature that is unsupported by this tool, it may be difficult to test it
3. [testegration](https://github.com/piotrturski/testegration) - intents to provide you full, ready to use and extensible lifecycle (disclosure: i'm a creator).

   cons:

   - free only for small projects
   - very young project

you can also fill the gaps on your own (`ProcessBuilder`, executing custom scripts). as always it's a trade: time vs money